# JavaFX add data to a table

Tags: java, mysql, javafx, scenebuilder

I'm trying to add data to a JavaFX table.

I have a class GameOfThronesCharacter. I made several instances of it and am trying to insert it the data into a JavaFX table.

The table was made in FX scenebuilder and the fxml file is linked in main.
This is practice, I'm planning on linking it to a mysql table instead of hardcoding GoTCs once I get this part down.

The table is acting very weird and like creating a second table though.
https://youtu.be/1JVraOXVPIk

I don't know what I messed up, anyone mind helping me? here's the code:

**Main.java**

```
public class Main extends Application {

static Stage window;
static Scene FrontEnd;

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage)throws IOException {
    window = primaryStage;
     initialize();

        window.setTitle("Database Interface v1.0");
        window.setResizable(true);
        window.setScene(FrontEnd);
        window.show();
}

private void initialize() throws IOException {
    FrontEnd = new Scene(FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Frontend.fxml")));
    FrontEnd.getStylesheets().add("application.css");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
    }
}
```

**FrontEnd.fxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<Pane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.FrontEndController">
   <children>
      <TableView fx:id="table">
        <columns>
          <TableColumn fx:id="deletionColumn" editable="false" prefWidth="75.0" text="Delete" />
          <TableColumn fx:id="nameColumn" editable="false" prefWidth="75.0" text="Name" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="allegianceColumn" editable="false" prefWidth="75.0" text="Allegiance" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="positionColumn" editable="false" prefWidth="75.0" text="Position" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="salaryColumn" editable="false" prefWidth="75.0" text="Salary" />
        </columns>
      </TableView>
   </children>
</Pane>
```

**FrontEndController.java**

```
public class FrontEndController implements Initializable {

    public TableView<GameOfThronesCharacter> table;
    public TableColumn<GameOfThronesCharacter,String> nameColumn;
    public TableColumn<GameOfThronesCharacter,String> allegianceColumn;
    public TableColumn<GameOfThronesCharacter,String> positionColumn;
    public TableColumn<GameOfThronesCharacter,Double> salaryColumn;



    private ObservableList<GameOfThronesCharacter> getCharacters(){
        ObservableList<GameOfThronesCharacter> characters = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        characters.add(new GameOfThronesCharacter("Cersei","Lannister","Queen Regent",100000));
        characters.add(new GameOfThronesCharacter("Jaime","Lannister","King Slayer",80000));
        characters.add(new GameOfThronesCharacter("Tyrion","Lannister","Queen's Hand",60000));

        return characters;
    }



    @Override
    public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
        //nameColumn
        nameColumn = new TableColumn<>("Name");
        nameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("name"));

        //allegianceColumn
        allegianceColumn = new TableColumn<>("Allegiance");
        allegianceColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("allegiance"));

        //positionColumn
        positionColumn = new TableColumn<>("Position");
        positionColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("position"));

        //salaryColumn
        salaryColumn = new TableColumn<>("Salary");
        salaryColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("salary"));

        //table = new TableView<>();
        table.setItems(getCharacters());
        table.getColumns().addAll(nameColumn,allegianceColumn,positionColumn,salaryColumn);

    }
}
```

**GameOfThronesCharacter.java**

```
public class GameOfThronesCharacter {

    private String name;
    private String allegiance;
    private String position;
    private double salary;

    public GameOfThronesCharacter(){
    }

    public GameOfThronesCharacter(String name, String allegiance, String position, double salary){
        setName(name);
        setAllegiance(allegiance);
        setPosition(position);
        setSalary(salary);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAllegiance() {
        return allegiance;
    }

    public void setAllegiance (String allegiance){
            this.allegiance = allegiance;
    }

    public String getPosition() {
        return position;
    }

    public void setPosition(String position) {
            this.position = position;
    }

    public double getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    public void setSalary(double salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }       
}
```

Comment: Why are you creating a whole new set of columns in the controller and adding them to the table?

Comment: @James_D He probably got a `null pointer exception` error since he didn't preface any of his variables with `@FXML`. Which, btw OP, you should do.

Comment: @MichaelPickett You don't actually need that if the fields are `public` (though they should, of course, be `private`).

Comment: @James_D Interesting. I was not aware of that, but I've always used my fields are private.

Comment: I will commend the OP on this, though: "I'm planning on linking it to a mysql table instead of hardcoding GoTCs once I get this part down.": this is an excellent way to approach the project. If you make a completely separate class that retrieves the data from the database, you'll also be able to get that working independently, and then link the two together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the FXML file, you create the table columns and add them to the table's `columns` list:

```xml
  <TableView fx:id="table">
    <columns>
      <TableColumn fx:id="deletionColumn" editable="false" prefWidth="75.0" text="Delete" />
      <TableColumn fx:id="nameColumn" editable="false" prefWidth="75.0" text="Name" />
        <TableColumn fx:id="allegianceColumn" editable="false" prefWidth="75.0" text="Allegiance" />
        <TableColumn fx:id="positionColumn" editable="false" prefWidth="75.0" text="Position" />
        <TableColumn fx:id="salaryColumn" editable="false" prefWidth="75.0" text="Salary" />
    </columns>
  </TableView>
```

Then, in the controller, you create a whole new set of columns, and add all those to the table's `columns` list:

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
    //nameColumn
    nameColumn = new TableColumn<>("Name");
    nameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("name"));

    //allegianceColumn
    allegianceColumn = new TableColumn<>("Allegiance");
    allegianceColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("allegiance"));

    //positionColumn
    positionColumn = new TableColumn<>("Position");
    positionColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("position"));

    //salaryColumn
    salaryColumn = new TableColumn<>("Salary");
    salaryColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("salary"));

    //table = new TableView<>();
    table.setItems(getCharacters());
    table.getColumns().addAll(nameColumn,allegianceColumn,positionColumn,salaryColumn);

}
```

So, unsurprisingly, you end up with a duplicate set of columns.

Just remove the code that creates the second set of columns. (As an aside, it's better to make the fields public, and make them accessible to the `FXMLLoader` by annotating them `@FXML`):

```
public class FrontEndController implements Initializable {

    @FXML private TableView<GameOfThronesCharacter> table;
    @FXML private TableColumn<GameOfThronesCharacter,String> nameColumn;
    @FXML private TableColumn<GameOfThronesCharacter,String> allegianceColumn;
    @FXML private TableColumn<GameOfThronesCharacter,String> positionColumn;
    @FXML private TableColumn<GameOfThronesCharacter,Double> salaryColumn;



    private ObservableList<GameOfThronesCharacter> getCharacters(){
        ObservableList<GameOfThronesCharacter> characters = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        characters.add(new GameOfThronesCharacter("Cersei","Lannister","Queen Regent",100000));
        characters.add(new GameOfThronesCharacter("Jaime","Lannister","King Slayer",80000));
        characters.add(new GameOfThronesCharacter("Tyrion","Lannister","Queen's Hand",60000));

        return characters;
    }



    @Override
    public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
        //nameColumn
        nameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("name"));

        //allegianceColumn
        allegianceColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("allegiance"));

        //positionColumn
        positionColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("position"));

        //salaryColumn
        salaryColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("salary"));

        //table = new TableView<>();
        table.setItems(getCharacters());

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks James this solved my issue and more. I didn't know about the FXML annotation either to be honest, and have usually made things public  as a result.  I'm kind of self learning and I do miss quite a bit here and there, appreciate the help though good sir!